# How to import PDF.JS into Typescript using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm-install, pdf.js

I installed the PDF.JS npm packages and import the same in typescript file, but it does not work as expected. I used the below code to import the PDF.JS into typescript.

```
import { PDFJSStatic } from 'pdfjs-dist';
const PDFJS: PDFJSStatic = require('pdfjs-dist');
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(console.log);
```

and I am getting the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'pdfjs-dist'. app.ts 2   Active 
>   Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'require'. app.ts  3   Active

please provide your valuable suggestion and let me know what I am missed in it if any.

Answer (score 1):

App structure really matters while importing any modules,
you need to import this first into your root level ts file 
app.module.ts and even in tsconfig.app.json.

Comment: It was not working properly even if we import from root level.